# May Hamming Distance be applied on numerical data without converting into binary data?

Tags: python, binary, hamming-distance

I am working on various distance metrics.
Hamming distance is commonly applied on binary data and any integer may be converted into binary.
My question is: can we apply hamming distance on numerical data without first converting it to binary?

Comment: How would a Hamming distance for non encoded integers look like? Would there be "unused" numbers?

Comment: Integer data *is* binary data - how else are integers stored, and what conversion would you expect to do?

Comment: I want to apply hamming distance directly on float values without converting into binary.eg:
0.1232 and 1.2342 =?
130.23 and 89.23=?

Comment: @kaya3 thank you for your quick response.
i want to apply hamming distance on the decimal values without converting the decimal value into binary value.

Comment: @KlausD. hamming distance is a distance where we count the no. of one's in a binary data after computing XOR gate.
but my question is how we can apply HD without converting decimal value into binary value?

Comment: The Hamming distance is simply said the number for characters in two words that differ. For the same data this number might differ by **encoding** and the number of characters in the alphabet used. Two integers represented as a base 10 string is likely to have a smaller distance than the same integers as a base 2 (binary) string.

Comment: @KlausD. That i know about HD but i getting trouble in finding the HD between values eg:
1.032 and 0.187=?
but the values should not be converted into binary.

Comment: Since the Hamming distance is calculated on strings it is 4. 5 characters, only the period is the same.

Comment: @President James K. Polk Hi. Curious why tags such as [binary] had to be removed?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk well I don't really mind. I was initially brought here by a "late answer" review, then figured the question could use a little edit and that [binary] would improve findability.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 1):

I Know it's an old post but maybe my answer can help some people. first of all the Hamming distance is defined as in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVDtk.png) and is not suited for contius numbers. This is because case y==ŷ will never become true, since there are in theory unlimited real numbers in any range of real numbers. What you could do however is in a first step quantize you predefined range of real numbers. now you could apply eq. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVDtk.png), which could give you soemthing similar to Hamming distance

[equation for hamming distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVDtk.png)

standard Himming for a integer vector (could be binary as well):

```
def hamming(q,k):
    distance=0
    for i in range(len(q)):
        if q[i] != k[i]:
            distance += 1
    return distance
```

code for the continous Hamming function:

```
def hamming_float(q,k,quat_step):
    distance=0
    for i in range(len(q)):
        if q[i] >= k[i]+quat_step or q[i] <= k[i]-quat_step:
            distance += 1
    return distance
```

Testing the code now for both cases:

```
#Standard Hamming
a=[0,1,2]
b=[0,1,4]
hamming(a, b)
#will return 1



#Hamming with float
a=[0,1,2]
b=[0,1.1,4]
hamming_float(a, b, 1)
#will also return 1
```